# How to set up Database for ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-2, import

I created an data driven ASP.NET MVC Application locally and it works fine. Within my App_Data Folder of my project i see two databases: ASPNETDB.mdf and myProjectDatabase.mdf.

I uploaded my project files an the webserver, so that I can actually open the website. But I couldn't figure out how to connect my Database that I created locally to that website. My Website uses Authentication so that it is necessary that a user logs in/registers. But because the database is not connected this obviously doesn't work, because the application needs a database to save and retrieve user information.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express and downloaded Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio as well to work with my database. With Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I already connected to my database with the login information my provider gave me. But how can I import my local databases? Do I need to import ASPNETDB.mdf as well, because that is where the user information are stored?

I would be very thankful for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of SQL Server do you have on your production server?  SQL Server Express can attach to those local MDF files.  If you're using SQL Server Standard, you'll need to attach them to the SQL Process.

Also, the ASPNETDB.MDB file is the authentication database that is automatically created in your MVC project.  That is the DB that stores usernames and passwords, so yes, you will need to move that database over as well.